# Why I can't change a single row?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

When I sort the data according to the value named "TC NO" and make the edits, all the data in the table changes. For example; I have a, b, and c values. I'm trying to make the value "a" to "d" but the values a,b, and c each convert to the value "d". I just want the value I selected to change. Where am I doing wrong?

[image: FormApp View]

```
public partial class muster_guncelleme : Form
{
    public muster_guncelleme()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=master; Trusted_Connection=True;";
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(conString);
    private void btn_arama_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baglanti.Open();
        string kayit = "SELECT * from [user] where tc_no=@tc_no";
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(kayit, baglanti);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tc_no", txt_tc.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(komut);
        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read()) 
        {
            lbl_tc.Text = dr["tc_no"].ToString();
            txt_user.Text = dr["user_name"].ToString();
            txt_pass.Text = dr["password"].ToString();
            txt_name.Text = dr["full_name"].ToString();
            bday_date.Text = dr["birth_date"].ToString();
            txt_phone.Text = dr["phone_number"].ToString();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Müşteri Bulunamadı.");
        baglanti.Close();
    }
    private void muster_guncelleme_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void btn_kaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baglanti.Open();
        string kayit = "update [user] set user_name=@user_name, password=@password, full_name=@full_name, phone_number=@phone_number";
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(kayit, baglanti);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", txt_user.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_pass.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", txt_name.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_number", txt_phone.Text);
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        baglanti.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Kullanıcı Bilgileri Güncellendi.");
    }
}
```

Comment: your `UPDATE` statement does not have a `WHERE` clause

Comment: I struggle to understand your question. Looking at your code, do you realize that your Update statement effects the whole table and not use a single row? eg. you are missing `where UserId = @userId`

Comment: yes I am aware that changed the whole table. I want to prevent this.

Comment: Okay I get it thx for the comments.